# python's lxml and iterparse method

Tags: python, lxml

Say i have this sample XML.

```
<result>
    <field k='field1'>
        <value h='1'><text>text_value1</text></value>
    </field>
    <field k='field2'>
        <value><text>text_value2</text></value>
    </field>
    <field k='field3'>
        <value><text>some_text</text></value>
    </field>
</result>
```

Using python's lxml, how can i get the value of each field for every result set?  So basically, i want to iterate over ever result set, then iterate over every field in that result set and print the text data.

This is what i have so far:

```
context = etree.iterparse(contentBuffer, tag='result')
for action, elem in context:
    print elem.tag, elem.data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is the code that i came up with.  It seems a bit clunky having to call getparent() twice to read the attribute of corresponding text value.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
for action, elem in context:
    list = elem.xpath('//text')
    print "result set:"
    for item in list:
        field = item.getparent().getparent().attrib['k']
        value = item.text
        print "\t%s = %s"%(field, value)
```

Comment: what do you expect the output of a working script to be?

Comment: i would like to print the field name(in the attr) = value(text).  I'd like the fields to be grouped with the other fields in that result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
import io
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
<result>
    <field k='field1'>
        <value h='1'><text>text_value1</text></value>
    </field>
    <field k='field2'>
        <value><text>text_value2</text></value>
    </field>
    <field k='field3'>
        <value><text>some_text</text></value>
    </field>
</result>'''

contentBuffer=io.BytesIO(content)
context = ET.iterparse(contentBuffer,tag='result')
for action, elem in context:
    fields=elem.xpath('field/@k')
    values=elem.xpath('field/value/text/text()')
    for field,value in zip(fields,values):
        print('\t{f} = {v}'.format(f=field,v=value))
```

which yields

```
field1 = text_value1
field2 = text_value2
field3 = some_text
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a [XPath query](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html). Something along `r = tree.xpath('//text')` should be sufficient for your needs.