# How can I get the only element of a certain type out of a list more cleanly than what I am doing?

Tags: python, lxml

I am working with some xml files.  The schema for the files specifies that there can only be one of a certain type of element (in this case I am working with the footnotes element).

There can be several footnote elements in the footnotes element, I am trying to grab and process the footnotes element so that I can iterate through it to discover the footnote elements.

here is my current approach

```
def get_footnotes(element_list):
    footnoteDict=od()

    footnotes_element=[item for item in element_list if item.tag=='footnotes'][0]
    for eachFootnote in footnotes_element.iter():
        if eachFootnote.tag=='footnote':
            footnoteDict[eachFootnote.values()[0]]=eachFootnote.text
    return footnoteDict
```

element_list is a list of elements that are relevant for me after iterating through the entire tree

So I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to get the footnotes element instead of iterating through the list of elements it seems to me that this is clumsy with this being

```
footnotes_element=[item for item in element_list if item.tag=='footnotes'][0]
```

Comment: You should have a look at this question and its answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692/how-to-use-xpath-in-python). Perhaps you should be using XPath and lxml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
from lxml import etree

xmltree = etree.fromstring(your_xml)

for footnote in xmltree.iterfind("//footnotes/footnote"):
   # do something
   pass
```

It's easier to help if you provide some sample XML.

**Edit:**

If you are working with really big files, you might want to look into `iterparse`.

This question seems to have quite a nice example: [python's lxml and iterparse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501572/pythons-lxml-and-iterparse-method)

Comment: You are suggesting instead of getting the relevant elements from the tree that I pass the full tree.  This is an interesting suggestion and I need to think about it some.  I am first running a function that pulls the parents of the elements I care about into element_list  and passing that list around to my other functions.  Your suggestion is that I just take the tree and pass it around.  My thought was that some of the trees I am working with are massively big so by ripping out the elements I want in a function I am getting rid through garbage collection of the other stuff that is not needed

Comment: If you're working with really big files you should look into `iterparse`. It allows you to extract data as a file is being parsed instead of parsing the entire file first and keeping it in memory.

Comment: @PyNEwbie, you wouldn't be passing the "whole tree" around, just a reference to it.