# lxml iterparse, child with same tag name

Tags: python, xml, django, scrapy, lxml

I want to parse xml on fly from file (1,5gb file) which looks like:

```
<product product_id="x" name="x" sku_number="x">
    <category>
        <primary>x</primary>
        <secondary>y</secondary>
    </category>
    <URL>
        <product>URL__I_WANT_TO_PULLOUT</product>
        <productImage>x</productImage>
    </URL>
    <description>
        <short>x</short>
        <long>x</long>
    </description>
</product>
```

I'm using `lxml.etree.iterparse` like:

```
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(f, events=('end',), tag='product'):
    save_product(elem)
```

I get all required values from xml nodes. The only node that I can't pull out is `URL>product` (it's just empty). I think that it's caused by same tag name. Is there any way to parse xml on fly, besides `iterparse`?

Comment: if you change the name for a sample, does it then work?

Comment: I haven't tried, but It's external data feed, so I'm not in charge of changing it

Answer (score 2):

If I run `etree.iterparse` on your sample it finds `'product'` tag two times: there is one external and one internal `<product>`. The external tag has child elements and its `text` is empty. So you need to skip those external `'product'` tags to work only with those that have no child elements, for example:

```
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=('end',), tag='product'):
    if not len(elem):
        save_product(elem)
```

---

If it is needed to handle all elements of the top `product` tag it is possible to drop all internal `product` fields in the main loop and then handle all child elements by path, for example [python's lxml and iterparse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501572/pythons-lxml-and-iterparse-method):

```
def save_product(elem):
    cat_prim = elem.xpath('category/primary')[0].text;
    cat_sec = elem.xpath('category/secondary')[0].text;
    url_prod = elem.xpath('URL/product')[0].text;
    url_img = elem.xpath('URL/productImage')[0].text;
    desc_short = elem.xpath('description/short')[0].text;
    desc_long = elem.xpath('description/long')[0].text;

for event, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=('end',), tag='product'):
    if len(elem):
        save_product(elem)
```

Comment: That's right but I'm building product data, so I need both (child nodes of external <product>, and text from internal <product>) at the same time.

Comment: @mdargacz What is the problem? Inside the loop or in the `save_product` function you can distinguish internal `<product>` and top `<product>` tag, so they can be handled differently according to your needs.

Comment: yes they can be handled differently, but there are strictly related, and if I have dozens of Products, can I be sure that next  internal <product> after parsing the top one, contains that product url? And even if thats true  I can make tuples of (top <product>, internal <product>) and then save_product(). But I would prefer not do to this in such a hacky way.

Comment: @mdargacz It works in this way, but I am not sure that is good to do such assumptions at least if it is not clearly specific the library documentation. Anyway the code structure is much better if you have one main loop for top `product` elements and separate handler for its fields. I updated the answer by such example.

Comment: but  this: url_prod = elem.xpath('URL/product/text()');   won't work, because node is empty at this moment

Comment: @mdargacz Child nodes are not empty since the top tag is fully read (it is the `'end'` event). It is from the working example, however it returns the result as a list: `['URL__I_WANT_TO_PULLOUT']`. It is possible to read the list elements directly. I updated the answer.

Comment: If it worked, I wouldn't create this question :)  It doesn't for me I get None at elem.xpath('./URL/product')[0].text

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be quite late but for anyone out there I used a following solution:

```
   file_contents = xml_file.read()
   xml_obj = etree.fromstring(file_contents)
   context = xml_obj.xpath(tag)
```

where my `tag` variable was was the path to the product e.g. `//parent/product`. Then you can use the context container to do something with your elements.